# Why minus sign in definition of angular momentum field density tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, conventions, continuum-mechanics

The following generalization of angular momentum is given on page 571 of the third edition of Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics*:$$\mathcal M^{ij}=-(x^iT^{j0}-x^jT^{i0}).\tag{13.44}$$The metric used in this case is the Lorentzian one with signature $(+,-,-,-)$.

Since the ordinary relativistic generalization is given by, $$m^{\mu\nu}=x^\mu p^\nu -x^\nu p^\mu ,$$ why does the generalization to continuous systems require the minus sign. I can see that the sign in no way affects the proof of the need to symmetrize the stress energy tensor for conservation of angular momentum. I have thought that perhaps it comes from the purely spatial nature of $\mathcal M^{ij}$, however, since the $x^\mu$ are naturally "raised" in the convention of Goldstein's text, or at least they appear to be at the top of page 293, this does not seem to be right. Help would be appreciated thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Minus signs are almost always a matter of convention. Have you verified that this is NOT the case here first?

Comment: @Prahar I am not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: Minus signs are often a matter of conventions. Different authors use different notations and conventions and often define angular momentum (and many other quantities) by different signs. Sometimes authors will change sign conventions mid-book/text or have sign typos. The most likely answer to your question is probably "author uses different sign conventions". Your first step should be to check whether this is the case.

Comment: Thanks Prahar, you have clarified my thinking. The ensuing calculations in the section are such that it is impossible to tell whether the convention was changed, thus the  options *are* typo or change of convention; neither of which affect the result. So, in this case the two options are equivalent.

Comment: I wonder about the usefulness of this post, should it be deleted?

Comment: If you have managed to figure that this is indeed a simple sign error in the book, you can write an answer yourself for anyone else who might be confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, how pesky are such offending minus signs to the novitiate, and yet far more nefarious are subtle and sly typographical errors.

It is impossible to tell with certainty that the minus sign in the definition of $\mathcal M^{ij}$ is a typographical error or a change in convention. Out of deference of Goldstein's venerable text it is safe to say that it is a change of convention for reasons I have yet to uncover. One may feel safe to use whatever convention one likes, i.e. with or without the minus sign, so long as the choice is consistent without any untoward effect.

Prahar's sagacious comments were most helpful, and the next time I am beset in this fashion I will think long and hard before commencing to pulling out my hair. To my credit, I did check the errata for the text, but nothing was there noted. The lesson is that: one should carefully decide whether the offending minus sign actually matters, if it does not, then it is with out any loss of generality a convention; if it does matter, then it is an error.

Perhaps, occasionally, it is good that the obvious be stated.